# TensorflowJS universal sentence encoder in WebWorker

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, web-worker, tensorflow.js

Trying to run USE in webworker to avoid performance issues, but it lacks embed() method.

#### WebWorker

```
importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.2.9/dist/tf.min.js');
importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder@1.1.1/dist/universal-sentence-encoder.min.js');
tf.setBackend('cpu');

onmessage = message => {
  use.load().then(model => {
    const sentences = [
      'I like my phone.',
      'Your cellphone looks great.'
    ];
    /**
      model = { model, tokenizer }
    */
    model.embed(sentences).then(async embeddings => {
      const vec = await embeddings.array();
      const cosine = tf.losses.cosineDistance(vec[0], vec[1], 0);
      const result = await cosine.data();
      console.log(`${Math.round((1 - result) * 100)}%`);
    });
  });
}
```

There is no embed() inside model which is the case for main thread
Is it even possible to run USE in webworkers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Universal Sentence Encoder (USE) can be used in a webworker. See below this working snippet with the result sent from the worker to the main thread

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.2/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
 <script>
        const worker_function = () =>
{
 importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.2.9/dist/tf.min.js');
 importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder@1.1.1/dist/universal-sentence-encoder.min.js');
 tf.setBackend('cpu');
 onmessage = message =>
 {
        console.log("from worker")
  use.load().then(model =>
  {
   const sentences = [
    'I like my phone.',
    'Your cellphone looks great.'
   ];
   model.embed(sentences).then(async embeddings =>
   { 
                console.log(await embeddings)
    const vec = await embeddings.array();
    const cosine = tf.losses.cosineDistance(vec[0], vec[1], 0);
    const result = await cosine.data();
                console.log(`${Math.round((1 - result) * 100)}%`);
                
                postMessage({res: cosine.dataSync(), shape: cosine.shape})
            });
            
  });
 };
}
if (window != self)
 worker_function();
    </script>
 <script>
        const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["(" + worker_function.toString() + ")()"], { type: 'text/javascript' })));
        worker.postMessage({});
        worker.onmessage = (message) => {
            console.log('from main thread')
            const {data} = message
         tf.tensor(message.data.res, message.data.shape).print()
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: That's weird, my `model` has only two properties (model and tokenizer) for some reason. Could you tell what's in your `model` object?

Comment: model has two properties: model and tokenizer, but on the prototype, we can see that there are the methods: `load`, `embed`, `loadModel`. If you are using typeScript, the error is related to the type inferred by typeScript rather than the library. You can just consider casting the `model` object to `any` and the error will disappear. Or you can consider giving a type to model that allows to use embed

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I can't use async-await in webworkers (React app with Webpack) and had to fallback to promises. I guess it's something Weback specific, but it cost me a day. Maybe you know the reason for such behavior of webworkers?